# float vs int in cuda

Tags: cuda

Is it better to use a `float` instead of an `int` in CUDA?

Does a `float` decrease bank conflicts and insure coalescence? (or has it nothing to do with this?)

Comment: they have same size, but different purpose

Answer (score 5):

Bank conflicts when reading shared memory are all about the amount of data read. So, since `int` and `float` are the same size (at least I think they are on all CUDA platforms), there's no difference.

Coalescence usually refers to global memory accesses - and again, this is to do with the number of bytes read, not the datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Both `int` and `float` are four bytes, so it doesn't make any difference (if you're accessing them both the same way) which you use in terms of coalescing your global memory accesses or bank conflicts on shared memory accesses.

Having said that, you may have better performance with `float`s since the devices are designed to crunch them as fast as possible, `int`s are often used for control and indexes etc. and hence have lower performance. Of course it's really more complicated than that - if you had nothing but floats then the integer hardware would sit idle which would be a waste.

Comment: Ints are around 10x slower in a typical GTX card. There are much fewer integer units on a typical GPU. Don't use ints or double width floats unless you have a specific reason to.

Comment: @KatasticVoyage It depends on what you're doing with them. For addition and subtraction, floats and ints are the same on devices with compute capability >= 5.0 (I've confirmed this with testing) and are within 20% of each other on other devices. See [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions).

Answer (score 1):

Bank conflicts and coalescence are all about memory access patterns (whether the threads within a warp all read/write to different locations with uniform stride). Thus, these concerns are independent of data type (float, int, double, etc.)

Note that data type does have an impact on the computation performance. Single precision float is faster than double precision etc. The beefy FPUs in the GPUs generally means that doing calculations in fixed point is unnecessary and may even be detrimental.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "Mathematical Functions" section of CUDA Developers Guide. Using device runtime functions (intrinsic functions) may provide better performance for various types. You may perform multiple operations in one operation within less clock cycles.

> For some of the functions of SectionC.1,a less accurate, but faster version exists inthe device runtime component; it has the same name
>   prefixed with __ (such as __sinf(x)).. The compiler has an option 
>   (-use_fast_math ) that forces each function in Table to compile to its intrinsic counterpart... selectively replace mathematical function
>   calls by calls to intrinsic functions only where it is merited by the
>   performance gains and where changed properties such as reduced
>   accuracy and different special case handling can be tolerated.

- For example instead of using => use: x/y =>  __fdividef(x, y); sinf(x) => __sinf(x)

And you may find more methods like x+c*y being performed with one function..